# recording terminal inputs in java

Tags: java

I am developing a tool for my school lab. In which Student uses terminal and I want to extract there input record for instructor (log file). I know file input output and so far I have been successful to open terminal. Using this

in class data

```
Process pr;
```

In function

```
String command= "/usr/bin/xterm"; 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
try {
    pr = rt.exec(command);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

and to exit the terminal, I am using,(if condition because student might not have yet opened terminal and log out)

```
if(pr!=null)
    pr.destroy();
```

Now in logout part I want to exit terminal and store the input log.
Need some pointer on how to get out inputs.

Comment: So you actually have 2 seperate program? one that you run when someone login which opens the terminal, and the other will run when the user logout? From you code your variable pr seems to hold the process but I don't see any while loop in between those code....wouldn't it cause the  program to start the terminal and end it immediately? maybe you should post all of you code if it's not too lengthy.

Comment: no, I have GUI on which open terminal and logout buttons are. and I am writing in event handler. The null pointer problem is no more there, I was using pr in other object and or wasn't static.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea will this work or not, I can't test it now and it's very hard to put code in comment. feedbacks are welcome.

try putting these code in your logout section and see what happens.

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
```

Comment: its getting stuck at line line = input.readLine() (I checked this by separating while loop). Should I destroy pr first? If I do that it doesn't get stuck but gives nothing in output.

Comment: did you try typing things into the console after it opens? that while loop i gave is basically reading the output of the console, but like I said, this is a pure guess, all I know is that the code I provide will work for a certain process, like in my case, task manager for windows, which i extract the active process list. I am purely guessing that it MIGHT work on your console.

Comment: yes, It was getting stuck at that line, so to find out why I used just this line String line= input.readLine(); and program is getting stuck here

Comment: if I close terminal first then logout then it prints null

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10135/how-to-write-terminal-contents-into-a-file) on Unix and Linux provides an answer to your question:

How about running the program like this:

```
program > /path/to/file
```

This redirects the output of program to /path/to/file instantly.

You can add arguments to your process call using `execute(String[] cmdarray)` with your command and the arguments, so `rt.execute(command, ">", "path/to/file");`

And if you want to have the output in your terminal, as well as save it into a file. Once the data is in the file, it will be really easy to read out of the file.